# Winsock и юникод

Tags: c++, c, winsock, unicode

Как отправить через winsock unicode-строку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сокетам абсолютно все равно, что передавать. Вопрос только в том, как клиент интерпретирует полученные данные